# Keep an image selected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a program which allows the user to select some images and i gave them the pseudo class

```
.my_image_clas:hover{
 border:3px solid blue;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; }
```

to make them surrounded with borders when the pointer goes over (giving a "selected effect"). I'd like to keep this effect even when i select the image, like this :[image]

How can i achieve this? (With javascript)

Comment: you need javascript for this. you cant handle it only with css.

Comment: You can't do that with CSS...you need Javascript.

Comment: Ok no problem, some advice with javascript?

Comment: create an `onclick` listener and then add a css class to selected item.

Comment: my advice: transform your markup into a regular form with checkbox and/or radiobox, and place those images as content of your labels (with a `for` attribute) . Use the `:checked` pseudoclass to style the label with the border, so javascript is not necessary at all. So try this approach and if you're stuck on some problem edit your question and share your code

Comment: You can do it with CSS... in fact some might argue it's better as then you can treat the images as radio buttons or checkboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CSS-only "hack"

At first this question asked for CSS-only solution and while, as others have said, it's not really possible to achieve what you ask for without JavaScript, there is a CSS-only hack, however:

```css
img {
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100px;
}
img:hover, img:target {
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a"><img id="a" src="https://farm1.static.flickr.com/640/23366158776_3bddebe005_t.jpg" /></a>
<a href="#b"><img id="b" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Marsglobe_tiny2.jpg" /></a>
```

It works by making your images a target of a click on an anchor they are contained in. We can style elements that are link targets, because we have a selector for that in CSS.

Note that this way you can select only one image.

---

### Pure JavaScript

If you want to do it with JavaScript though, you can use below code:

```js
function select(element) {
  element.onclick = function() {
    element.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('selectable')).forEach(select);
```

```css
img {
  margin: 3px;
}
.selected {
  border: 3px solid green;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<img class="selectable" src="https://farm1.static.flickr.com/640/23366158776_3bddebe005_t.jpg" />
<img class="selectable" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Marsglobe_tiny2.jpg" />
```

It works by toggling class named `selected` on click for every element with class `selectable`. Also, it will let you select multiple items.

If you want to limit the user to selecting only one element though, change the above JavaScript to:

```
function select(element) {
  element.onclick = function() {
    var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected')[0];
    if (typeof selected !== 'undefined') { selected.classList.remove('selected'); }
    if (element !== selected) { element.classList.add('selected'); }
  }
}

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('selectable')).forEach(select);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very useful!

Comment: The first one with CSS only doesn't work to me, because i'm using an array and I can't set images as links

Comment: Can i select once at time in javascript?

Comment: @FrancescoMonti: Sorry for a bit long reaction time, but I've added single-item select in JavaScript as you wanted. If you clarify to me why CSS way doesn't work for you I may be able to overcome the problem and help you further. One case in which CSS way won't work as intended though, is when you use anchors to another elements in the rest of your code. In this case clicking such anchor would unselect your image.

Answer (score 3):

You may use jQuery here for hovering effects, jQuery provides the hover() pseudo-event, which behaves better than moueseenter/mouseleave. Also, it's a good idea to create a CSS class for each state (normal and hovered), and then change the class on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my_image_clas").hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass("Hover"); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass("Hover"); }
    );
});

.my_image_clas.Hover { border: 3px solid blue; }
```

@Francesco Monti I've read your comment.

for working with jquery you may add jquery.js under the head tag of your html

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

or adding online would be

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

and you can use `$(document).ready(function()` under the script tags.

If you want you can separate js & css files and includes those files accordingly.

Comment: @Francesco  I've added some basic steps hope it helps! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to try it out!

Comment: Most welcome! Please accept my answer if helped ! thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work, but i'im probably doing something wrong. In my HTML page i wrote `<script src="../scripts/Script.js"></script>` and then `$(document).ready(function())` right under the script tags.

Comment: Okay!! is your js is loading properly ? for that you can do ctrl + U and find your js path and file as well , if not please make a correct call! :)

Comment: Is says that "{}" are expected after `$(document).ready(function()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104900/discussion-between-shashank-shah-and-francesco-monti).

Comment: @FrancescoMonti : what's wrong with my code? Unaccepted?!!

Comment: I didn't manage to run your code, and the one that now is selected is more complete

Comment: What makes you stop managing my code ?? & It Depends! I was there to give you online support! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104900/discussion-between-shashank-shah-and-francesco-monti Helping is cheap job i guess! :(

Comment: You are perfeclty right, i wish i could select 2 best replies!

Comment: No comments :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your approx CSS:

```
.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.item.selected,
.item:hover,
.item:focus {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Some basic jQuery:

```
$('.item').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default behavior if .item is a link or button

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```

Comment: Sorry but i've never worked with jQuery so far, should i write it in my external .js file?